# When is the first good moment to communicate between services

Tags: feathersjs

I have a feather service where every record must have a unique integer number. So I need a global *counter* for this.

I thought the correct way to do this is to create another service named *counter*, where I can store that counter. Then I tried to access that service in the constructor and failed. I assume it is not ready yet. So when is a good time to access it?

I want to copy the current counter to the service instance, so I can keep in a synchronous way and dont have doubles when having two concurrent requests.

Also when I use `setTimeout(() => this.prepare(), 0)` to deley the setup which seems to work I realize that the `this` passed to `async create()` is *not* the same this used in the `constructor`. When doing `setTimeout(() => this.foo = "test", 0)` then `this.foo` will *not* be `test` inside `async create()` later. Why is that?

Comment: Can you post some code?  What does "and failed" actually mean?  did you get a specific set of errors?

Comment: You need a database for this one and let the database handle the uniqueness for you.